# Firebase returns undefined value when code is used in provider method

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I use firebase code on ionic page to retrieve value from firebase db and this work OK.

I was planning to move the firebase code into a provider class and invoke the provider class method within my ionic page. So, rather than calling firebase from page, I will call provider from page and the provider will call firebase.

When I implement a method in the provider as shown below, and call this from the ionic page, the provider method returns undefined. I am guessing that this is because of asynchronous nature of firebase and the return is executed even before the value is set. How do I go about understanding this concept and fixing this? I was thinking that - instead of using .on; i should use .once that will return a promise, but not sure as I need to place the return line outside the firebase code/promise, so how do I make the return to wait?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by using .once and directly returning the statement as follows. The caller then uses the .then keyword to retrieve the data from the promise. [image: solution]